# Find item in array of strings to filter a flatlist

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filtering, react-native-flatlist

I have a `FlatList` that I am trying to filter with multiple inputs from dropdown selectors. Here is my `FlatList` component

```
      <FlatList
        style={styles.list}
        data={data.filter(filteredUsers)}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        ListEmptyComponent={EmptyItem}
      />
```

A sample item from the data object

```
  { id: "2", name: "Harry", city: "Scottdale", state: "AZ", instrument: ["Cowbell", "Ocarina"] },
```

And the `filterUsers` function that is working with a single string, which shows all items in the data object and filters down when a user starts selecting options from the dropdown. When cleared the full data list is shown again.

```
  const filteredUsers = (item: { state: string; instrument: string }) => {
    return (
      item.state.toLowerCase().indexOf(state.toLowerCase()) >= 0 &&
      item.instrument.toLowerCase().indexOf(instrument.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    )
  }
```

I'd like to have that same functionality after changing `instrument` to an array of strings rather than a single string.

Ive updated the instrument type in `filteredUsers` to `instrument: Array<string>` but can not figure out how to get the filtering to work as it did before I updated to the array. I appreciate any help and would happily provide more information if I left anything out. Thanks

Comment: May I please understand what is `instrumentValue` (in `filteredUsers` method)? Also: when I read the parameter `item: { state: string, instrument: string}`, I had (probably incorrectly imagined) that the parameter being sent into the `filteredUsers` method will be an object with exactly 2 props (ie, `state` and `instrument`).

Comment: Here's my attempt: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDGBvGASzgC4YAiAJnIBoYwEBbAUzPIAkEAnLgT1pjBCUXmwDKoKFEQAbZgOhJWFAIIAtAYUhQuAVxZgoZDOQDCIAO4AjZjJkDyAeWDctCcgF0YAXxo58RKQU1HQMLGycPPx0QiLiklAQsvJ0ilDK5Oqa2noGRpjkACqWNnYOzq4Mnj5+uATEbCH0TBmRfAKxohQSIFLJCsjpbAAKKtnQucyGxkUltvZ0TohcbtW+WB4A3FhYoNowacxoMADk6ifbe9BEOfpTsOgn5tbzFztXsABmhDLpXMxwACqEGYXAgxwAFMJmIwyAgwLwAJRoAB8+H8-ygui4YBgEP8uGhjAAdIdiVAQAAZSyg0wIEEQxHErRwZgAD0cnwhZIp1IstPpzEZyJR6AADDAAGSSglEdIkrQTO6GYkAKxAWkZ5KpNK4dIZTJZ7M5UNueW1fIFBpF4v8iKw3ne4AgIDkxJkIAA5hDEMhid9fqCIQG-gDgaCIIjEdsgA).

Comment: Hey @jsN00b your solution worked thank you so much! Please feel free to post it as the solution I will upvote and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be one implementation to achieve the desired objective:

Sample data:

```
const data = [
  { id: "2", name: "Harry", city: "Scottdale", state: "AZ", instrument: ["Cowbell", "Ocarina"] },
  { id: "2", name: "Harry", city: "Scottsdale", state: "AZ", instrument: ["Towbell", "Ocarina"] },
  { id: "2", name: "Harry", city: "Scottdale", state: "PA", instrument: ["Towbell", "Odarina"] },
];
```

Simulate the values that will be used to filter the data:

```
const state = 'AZ';
const instrument = 'Cowbell';
```

The `filteredUsers` method:

```
const filteredUsers = (item: any) => {
  return (
    item.state.toLowerCase().indexOf(state.toLowerCase()) >= 0 &&
    item.instrument.join().toLowerCase().indexOf(instrument.toLowerCase()) >= 0
  )
}
```

Invoke the filter manually:

```
console.log(data.filter(filteredUsers));
```

[**Link to TypeScript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDGBvGASzgC4YAiAJnIBoYwEBbAUzPIAkEAnLgT1pjBCUXmwDKoKFEQAbZgOhJWFAIIAtAYUhQuAVxZgoZDOQDCIAO4AjZjJkDyAeWDctCcgF0YAXxo58RKQU1HQMLGycPPx0QiLiklAQsvJ0ilDK5Oqa2noGRpjkACqWNnYOzq4Mnj5+uATEbCH0TBmRfAKxohQSIFLJCsjpbAAKKtnQucyGxkUltvZ0TohcbtW+WB4A3FhYoNowacxoMADk6ifbe9BEOfpTsOgn5tbzFztXsABmhDLpXMxwACqEGYXAgxwAFMJmIwyAgwLwAJRoAB8+H8-ygui4YBgEP8uGhjAAdIdiVAQAAZSyg0wIEEQxHErRwZgAD0cnwhZIp1IstPpzEZyJR6AADDAAGSSglEdIkrQTO6GYkAKxAWkZ5KpNK4dIZTJZ7M5UNueW1fIFBpF4v8iKw3ne4AgIDkxJkIAA5hDEMhid9fqCIQG-gDgaCIIjEdsgA)

**Explanation**

- The parameter passed into the `filteredUsers` method is set to be `any` (for brevity). It may be appropriate to declare the object's props instead of `any`.
- The values that will be used to filter are `state` and `instrument` and those are also declared separately (this may probably come from either `state` or `props`)
- When searching for `state` the existing logic applies
- When searching for `instrument`, the newly-transformed `Array` in the `item` is turned into a `string` (by using `.join`) and existing logic is applied to this new `string` (which is a concatenation of all elements of the `instrument` array).

NOTE: This is most-certainly not the best solution. And, I'm sure there are several points that need to be updated. Happy to learn more and update this.